# File Written in Chinese (I think?)

Tags: c, file, io

I have an assignment to create my own version of UNIX ar, in C. I broke the assignment up into several pieces and I am just trying to write the file names into another file(which will be my archive file) at this point. I can create the file, and when I use printfs to make sure I'm getting the proper arguments from the command line, the file names are correct. When I open the file that I have created that is suppose to hold those file names, everything is in an Asian language.

I've researched the problem and haven't found much to go on. The only thing I did find was something about the files being encoded differently, but I'm pretty confused at this point.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ar.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *file_name, *archive_name;
    size_t count = 50;
    int i, fd, num_written;

    //command line options to do later
    //argv[1]

    //get archive name
    archive_name = argv[2];

    //get file names to add to archive
    for (i = 3; i<argc; i++)
    {
        file_name = argv[i];
    }

    //create archive file
    fd = open(archive_name, O_RDWR |O_CREAT|O_APPEND);
    if (fd < 0){
        perror("Error while opening file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    else
        printf("File %s opened successfully\n", archive_name);


    //write file names into archive file
        for (i = 3; i<argc; i++)
    {
        printf("file name: %s\n", argv[i]);
        num_written = write(fd, argv[i], 50);
        if (num_written == -1){
            perror("Error while writing to archive.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

     }


    close(fd);

    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Learn to use the debugger (`gdb`). Avoid uninitialized variables (like `file_name` or `i`). Be afraid of [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Maybe the problem is your editor? Try a different editor, and check if it also displays chinese letters.

Comment: `num_written = write(fd, argv[i], 50);` How do you know that `argv[i]` is exactly 50 characters long?

Comment: I am compiling with gcc -Wall -g, there were no warnings or errors. I tried using a different text editor and tried changing the encoding, nothing worked. I don't know that it will be 50, I just hard coded it for now to test. It is a big project so I've just been working on getting small pieces to work and then fixing it up after. If it isn't 50 characters long wouldn't it just truncate the text, not encode it in another language?

Comment: You've told a story but you haven't asked a question. "I'm confused" is a fact, not a question. Ask a *specific* question.

Comment: If you are in general confused about what text encodings are, this is a good place to start: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is assuming all arguments after the archive name are 50 bytes long.  If the arguments are shorter than that, the program may crash or write random data.  Since it didn't crash, and Notepad (or whatever) seems to think it's Chinese, I'm going to assume it wrote the random data.  Use `strlen` to figure out how long each of the argument names are.

Additionally:
you check `argv[2]` without checking `argv`, which could cause a crash.
Nothing you do with `file_name` makes any sense.

Comment: Thank you every one for your help. I re-structured some functions and used the strlen function and was able to get it up and working.